# adding an on key up event on dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: jquery

I generating dynamic textboxes and I want to add a keyup event but I was doing so to each one individually with jQuery and it is not working. In the DOM based off of my code

```
                         `$('#dynamicTextBox').html('');
                            for (var i = 0; i < ui.value; i++) {
                                var textbox = $('<input type="text" class="txt' + i + '" />')
                                $('#dynamicTextBox').append(textbox);
                            }
                        }`
```

I get txt0  txt1 txt2  txt3  and so forth when those elements are appended. I just am simply trying to trigger an alert on an onkeyup but its is not being detected. I have tried

```
           $('input#txt0').on('keyup','.txt0', function() {
            dTxt0 = ui.value;
            changeValue();
           value = $(".txt0").val();   
          alert(value);
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current HTML you can use something like below.

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on("keyup", "input:text[class^='txt']", function(){
        var val = this.value;
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z2jgrzru/)**

It would be better if you can use a common class for these elements and generate unique ids in the loop.

Your HTML will look like

```
<input type="text" id="txt0" class="inpboxes" />
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="inpboxes" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" class="inpboxes" />
```

and the jQuery will change to

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on("keyup", "input:text.inpboxes", function(){
        var val = this.value;
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z2jgrzru/1/)**